# Geometric Proof for Slopes (Contined Fractions)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

I just started learning about continued fractions, and my lecture had a theorem that estimated the slope $a$ of a given line $L$. This was done in terms of the slope of the point $P$ with coordinates $(q,p)$. The proof in the lecture went through the case when $P$ was *below* $L$. However what I want to know is what would be a proof if $P$ was *above* $L$.

**Lecture Notes:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a link to my lecture if anyone needs it.

Comment: Seems a very interesting question, but can you show us that theorem and that proof?

Comment: @Pedro [Lecture Link](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod-edx/OHSX/Number_Theory/NUMTH39.mp4)

Comment: @WillJagy Can you help me out here, please?

Comment: Not sure why you mention me; in any case I lack the plug-ins to view your video. What book are you using?

Comment: @WillJagy I use the lectures

Comment: @WillJagy I added my lecture notes. Can you help me now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof of the dual case where $P$ is above $L$ is precisely the same, except you need to reverse the ordering in a few places. In fact,the theorem and proof is almost identical to Theorem 7.2 in Stark's *An introduction to number theory*. Following the proof Stark remarks

> We have of course only proved Theorem 7.2 when P is under L. In this 
>   and later theorems where we have the two choices of putting a point over or 
>   under a line, we will take one of the choices and leave the other choice for the 
>   reader. As expected, the proofs are practically identical with the modifications 
>   usually restricted to the words "over" and "above" being interchanged with 
>   "under" and "below". There are also occasional changes of directions of 
>   inequalities and changes of sign.

Comment: Is there a pdf of this book?

Comment: @JessieDoner Probably. You can find that page on [Amazon books](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Number-Theory-Harold-Stark/dp/0262690608) by searching for "practically identical". The lecture appears to be based on Stark's presentation.